# Does package author get notified by tagging his/her package inside my question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I don't know if this question has been asked before or not, but sometimes I fail to make some package working properly. Additionally, it may take long time to go through several similar questions to find a solution to (maybe) simple question.

So, I wonder if support can be given from the package author when I tag it in my question by means of notifying him/her on either TeX.SX account or his/her email.

Comment: I would greatly resent receiving such notifications. I would consider it unreasonable exploitation of contact details made available in good faith. If you have a question or problem, the courteous thing to do is to email me. I may not be able to help or may have no time to help. But I certainly won't object to being asked. But I would object very strongly to TeX SE emailing me or notifying me every time somebody tagged a question with a relevant package (even though this is very few questions in my case). [In contrast, I wouldn't object to notification from the TeX world, but that's not SE.]

Comment: Definitely, you should email the package author directly with your problem if it is specific and relevant enough. But, if you are not sure, it may be best to try it past the TeX SX community first. There are more people here who can help you figure which package is messing things up, also also, most of the time, solve your problem.

Comment: I have [an email notification set up](http://stackexchange.com/filters) when my package gets mentioned. Since I don’t maintain the package any more I don’t tend to answer questions about it as often any more, but I still might, once in a while.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there's no such automatic notification of package authors.

- Please be aware, that not every package/class author is a member of TeX.SX at all!
- The [tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) system can be applied in some sense of notification if users have the relevant tag in their mail notification ('newsletter') that there are new questions tagged with [tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) -- however, not every user of TeX.SX has enabled (me included)
- There are many users that can help you although they are not the author/maintainer of the package under consideration.
- Although most packages that are used in questions here can be found at CTAN, TeXLive or MikTeX, there are a lot of template packages etc. which are spread through the Internet nowadays and there's no clear authorship/maintainership any longer -- it would be difficult to notify the 'authors' of those packages.
- A [tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) - notification feature would be very `TeX.SX` specific, not any of the SE sites has the concept of `authors` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your information. The problem is many users can provide already working steps based on their own OS, Software versions, etc. So, deep level of package understanding may be needed which can be merely given by the author. I already faced two problems with two different packages, and it seemed that deep knowledge is eagerly needed for the solution.

Comment: In this case contacting the author/maintainer is perhaps the better option, especially if you have a feature request. For CTAN packages there's a maintainer/author mail address available

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I think you are overestimating the knowledge required to author a package and underestimating the knowledge of others. I seriously doubt that I'm in a better position to answer questions about my packages than everybody else. I'm sure I'm in a worse position than many members of this site.

Comment: @cfr: Depends on the complexity of the relevant package, I would say